# How to ignore files starting with # in git

Tags: git

i like to know if it's possible (and if its possible how it can be achieved) to ignore files starting with # in git via .gitignore. I already tried

```
\\#.myfile
```

with no luck.

Comment: That will only ignore that, i.e. #.myfile. Are all your files called #.something? Use \#.* then.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Here is the right syntax for that:

```
\#*
```