# Git: ignore file.ext1 only if file.ext2 exists

Tags: git, gitignore

To be precise, there is a project with a bunch of *.el and *.org files. When executed, from every file.org a file.el is generated. Now the .gitignore is being written. Is there a possibility to say that any file.el shall be ignored **only if** file.org is there, **otherwise** track file.el

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501022/git-ignore-generated-extensions) does not solve it. Neither does writing every single file in the .gitignore

Comment: Have you considered modifying the build so generated files are put in a separate folder?

Comment: I agree with @Mic, I think this is more like a flow issue, you can have a extra folder, for example /dist, in addition to your /generated, and extra task to populate that /dist folder. So generated files still get ignored, but not files in /dist folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with gitignore (I don't know of conditional ignore rules).

A workaround would be a bash script (works even on Windows) which would:

- find all `file.el`
- for each file, test if `file.org` exists
- if it does, use `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged file.el`

(or `git skip-worktree --no-assume-unchanged file.el`: see "[Difference Between '`assume-unchanged`' and '`skip-worktree`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806990/6309)"

But, as commented, it would be easier to separate generate from dist files, with only the former to be ignored.